# dynamic textbox are not store in the textbox

Tags: php, javascript

i m creating dynamic text box on onclick event the code is running properly text box are created but the problem is when i create new text box and fill the some value on the first text values are store properly and again create the new text box that time first text box value are automatically delete or null i m trying to solve this error but not getting answer properly please help me....

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Form</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
function changeIt()
{

createTextbox.innerHTML = createTextbox.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext' >"

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form">
<input type="button" value="clickHere" onClick="changeIt()">
<div id="createTextbox"></div>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand the question exactly. Please see if you can explain through this:http://jsfiddle.net/7Yz2f/

Comment: You also need to create unique names, as currently every added input will be named `mytext`. Easiest would be to make it an array - `<input type='text' name='mytext[]' >`

Comment: please run the code...
and click on clickHere button text box created and fill some value in text box and again create new text box that first text box value are null i want to store  this value in text.....

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function changeIt() {
            var divTag = document.createElement("input");
            document.body.appendChild(divTag);
        }
    </script>

<input type="button" value="Create"
        onclick="changeIt();" />
```

Comment: function changeIt() {
            var divTag = document.createElement("input");
            divTag.type="file";
            document.body.appendChild(divTag);
        }

Answer (score 0):

`createTextbox` is not explicitly available. You'll have to get it by using `document.getElementById`. Like this...

```
var createTextbox = document.getElementById("createTextbox");
createTextbox.innerHTML = createTextbox.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext' >";
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `createTextbox.innerHTML =`, you replace the current content of the div.

Use the `appendChild` function to solve it, here is one example:

```
function addInput(){
        //get the div element
        var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        //create an input element
        var i = document.createElement("input");
        //add it to the div
        d.appendChild(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeLink()
{
document.getElementById('createTB').innerHTML="<input type='text' />";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="createTB"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="changeLink()" value="Change link">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For details please visit http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_elmnt_innerhtml